# How to break the client and server communication?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have a client and server application running.
The communication is happening by using SOCKETs.

other than UNPLUGGING the LAN, is there a way out to break the communication?

Any idea?

Regards,
Sudheer

Comment: Switch one of them off?

Comment: Firing a shotgun at the cable works.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm pretty sure firing a shotgun directly at one of the computers also works. Or smashing it with a hammer, for that matter, if you are worried about damaging your desk.

Comment: Thanks guys for ur inputs... but I would like to break the communication abruptly. Do you see a way out?

Answer (score 0):

Send some string from the client to the sever for example "exit" and make the server check the value it receives on it's socket if it is equal to "exit" then close that client's socket on the server side and also on the client side

Comment: No.. I guess you got it wrong. I would prefer to break the connection abruptly like tcpkill command.